# How to import PGN file for Machine Learning

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am attempting to create a Dataframe in python in order to perform some machine learning tasks on a chess AI. I am having trouble printing out the Dataframe.

I am using pandas to read a csv file. This file was originally a pgn file that I simply saved as a csv file. I am using `pandas.head()` in attempts to read said file.

```
import pandas as pd
Fischer_games = pd.read_csv("/home/rhulain/Desktop/Python Projects/Fischer_ai/Fischer_dataset.csv", sep=".")
print(Fischer_games.head())
```

I expected to see the first 5 items of the csv file as separated at each period. This would be the first 5 moves within the first chess game within the file.

Instead I get this error:

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 3

My intuition says that the formatting of the csv file is somehow in such a way that the pandas parser isn't handling it well. In that case, I am unsure how to format the information within the csv file to have pandas properly read it.

Comment: Did you convert the png file into `numpy` array?

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation), a Portable Game Notation file is **not** a csv file. Have you pre-processed it, or at least could you show the beginning of the file?

Comment: @SergeBallesta  The file contains game information and moveset. Example: [Event "USA-chJ"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "1955.??.??"]
[Round "?"]
[White "Thomason, J."]
[Black "Fischer, Robert James"]
[Result "0-1"]
[WhiteElo ""]
[BlackElo ""]
[ECO "E91"]

1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 g6 3.Nc3 Bg7 4.e4 d6 5.Nf3 O-O 6.Bd3 Bg4 7.O-O Nc6 8.Be3 Nd7
9.Be2 Bxf3 10.Bxf3 e5 11.d5 Ne7 12.Be2 f5 13.f4 h6 14.Bd3 Kh7 15.Qe2 fxe4
16.Nxe4 Nf5 17.Bd2 exf4 18.Bxf4 Ne5 19.Bc2 Nd4 20.Qd2 Nxc4 21.Qf2 Rxf4 22.Qxf4 Ne2+
23.Kh1 Nxf4  0-1

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The issue was in blank data columns being read as data.

Following code fixed it:

```
bob_games = pd.read_csv("/home/rhulain/Desktop/Python Projects/bob_ai/Fischer_dataset.csv", sep='delimiter', header=None)
```